# Toggle Button - Beveled Effect

Tags: wpf, togglebutton

I've been trying to create a toggle button with a "simple" bevel effect for my WPF Window. At first I've tried to apply the BevelBitmapEffect but apparently it is not deprecated and there are no visual changes when applied.
I've have tried many other "tweaks" with no success.

The kind of button I'm going for is something like this:
[image: Beveled Button]

**Edit:** I was able to create this effect by having two pictures (unpressed and pressed). Still, if anyone knows how to do this without any external resources that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options for this,

1. Create a Style for the ToggleButton that gives the desired look, [this page](http://wpf.2000things.com/tag/togglebutton/) has an example of a simple style for a toggle button.
2. Make a toggle button custom control, which is the same idea but can be a bit simpler if you need to use the same style in multiple places or applications.